# Proxies priority algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, http, web, proxy

I have a service that uses proxies. The Service makes a lot of requests over those proxies. I've defined a task that pings those proxies in every 10 minutes. But proxies often fall down for several requests and after that they revive. So I came up with a simple solution that summarize count of falls down during one hour. And I use this property like priority. It means that service get only alive proxy with higher priority. (With less count of falls down)

So my question: is there an "special" algorithm to make this process more "smart"? Smart priority for proxies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there clearly is. You're only using one parameter of the proxies, namely 'count of falls down during one hour', to prioritize proxies, whereas a lot of other factors could be taken into account. You could, for instance, also look at resource usage, response times, and number of active requests.

I would lower the duration of the time-slices, in which you change the priorities, to have the whole system respond better to problems.

I'm sorry my answer has to stay this vague, but your question doesn't give much detail either.

PS: I'm surprised you seem to accept the fact that your proxies fall down. That means that service requests are not fulfilled, and I would think that is unacceptable.